# Encoding SQL PDO SQL results

Tags: php, json, web-services, utf-8

I am using a PHP web service to get results from an sql query within one of the tables has quotes and when I use the query below it the result shows this table as null. Now I had this issue already and what I had to do was encode the array then with `utf8_encode`. However that doesn't seem to work now. How can I now encode my results to show the table in my json results.

My code is below

```
$id = 14;
include("file.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_id='$id'";
$sth = $dbc->query($query);
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
$result = utf8_encode($result);
/* output in necessary format */

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $_GET['onJSONPLoad'];
echo "(" . json_encode($result) . ")";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue it seems that I had to set the PDO itself to utf8. The code below worked

`$dbc = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`

Comment: You should mark this as the answer then.  Surely someone will be able to use it.  I erased my suggestions.

Comment: cannot mark it as the answer until tomorrow but I will do that